# Custom CalloutView with Swift 2.0 Best Approach?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I want to create a custom `CalloutView` from `xib`. I created a xib and custom `AnnotationView` class. I want to use my `MapViewController` segue which name is `showDetail` segue because this segue is a **Push** segue. When the user taps the button in my calloutView it should perform my `showDetail` segue.

I searched all documents, tutorials, guides and questions but I could
not find a any solution with **Swift**. There are no custom libraries also. I couldn't find any solution it as been 3 days.

My `CalloutView.xib` file `View` is my CustomAnnotationView which name is `CalloutAnnotationView.swift` and **File's Owner** is `MapViewController` it allows me to use `MapViewController` segues.

There is my `CalloutAnnotationView.swift`

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
        if (hitView != nil) {
            self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
        }
        return hitView
    }

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let rect = self.bounds
        var isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)
        if (!isInside) {
            for view in self.subviews {
                isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)
                if (isInside) {

                }
            }
        }
        return isInside
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        let calloutViewController = MapViewController(nibName: "CalloutView", bundle: nil)

        if selected {

            calloutViewController.view.clipsToBounds = true
            calloutViewController.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            calloutViewController.view.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width * 0.5, -calloutViewController.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5)
            self.addSubview(calloutViewController.view)


        } else {
            // Dismiss View
            calloutViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

My `MapViewController.swift` codes;

```
// MARK: - MapKit Delegate Methods

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if let annotation = annotation as? Veterinary { // Checking annotations is not User Location.
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(Constants.MapViewAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier) as? CalloutAnnotationView
            if pinView == nil { // If it is nil it created new Pin View
                pinView = CalloutAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: Constants.MapViewAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
                pinView?.canShowCallout = false
            } else { pinView?.annotation = annotation } // If it is NOT nil it uses old annotations.
            // Checking pin colors from Veterinary Class PinColor Method
            pinView?.image = annotation.pinColors()
            //pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)

            return pinView
        }
        return nil
    }
```

These codes are working fine to load my xib file. I created `IBAction` from a **button** and It **performs** segues from `MapViewController`to my `DetailViewController` with `showDetail` segue. **But problem is** It doesn't remove my **customCalloutView** from `superview` so I can't **dismiss** callout views.

How can I solve this problem or What is the best way to create custom `calloutView` for use my `MapViewController` push segues ?

**Thank you very much.**

Answer (score 0):

In your MKMapView delegate see if this gets called when segueing:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
   if let annotation = view.annotation as? Veterinary {
        mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you with the problem

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view.isKindOfClass(AnnotationView)
    {
        for subview in view.subviews
        {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```